# @font-face working on original, but not on new file I'm working on?

Tags: html, css, font-face, embedded-fonts, webfonts

It's easier to just provide links and show the issue, so here goes:

The old file: http://demo41.abcguide.com/index.php

And here's the new file I'm working on:

http://demo41.abcguide.com/slice.html

I've copied the @font-face directly from the old CSS, but it's not showing the font on the new slice.html file.. help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest `@font-face` declarations within `@media`.  They must be in the root of your CSS document to work, and so they are currently being ignored.